# Как сделать, чтобы при изменении данных в таблице DataGrid изменялись данные в БД ADO Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, ado.net

Есть созданная таблица в WPF, создается так:

```
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            string cmd = "SELECT FIO, login,password,Role FROM Users";
            SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, sqlConnection);
            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(createCommand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Users"); // В скобках указываем название таблицы
            dataAdp.Fill(dt);
            Adm_users.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; // Сам вывод 
            sqlConnection.Close();
```

Необходимо, чтобы данные, которые изменил пользователь в таблице при пользовании программой изменялись и в БД.

Comment: Вопрос сводится к тому, как при обновлении DataTable обновить базу, копать туда.

Comment: клиент-серверное приложение подразумевает использование каких-нибудь действий для сохранения результатов изменений, например даже в Excel есть кнопка сохранить, в связи с этим разумно разделять подход сохранения данных и подход отображения.
Отображение сделать с помощью связки и MVVM, а сохранение по кнопке через ICommand